# Is it possible to store JVM options in a file?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have a Tomcat application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk or my local machine.

Whenever I want to start the application, I have to pass many `-Dkey=value` options to it.

The value of these options depends on which environments (e.g., dev, prod, staging, or qa, ....) I'm running at.

Is it possible to store those sets of options in a file (let's say `qa.properties`, `dev.properties`, or `prod.properties`, ...) so that I can pass something like `-property_file=dev.properties` to JVM to start the java application in a development environment?

Passing `-property_file=dev.prperties` to JVM is more elegant than passing `-Ddev_key1=dev_value1 -Ddev_key2=dev_value2 -Ddev_key3=dev_value3 ...` to JVM.

I don't find such an option in `java -help`.

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.


    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

Comment: Have you considered putting those options into `bin/setenv.bat` or `bin/setenv.sh` in your tomcat folder? More precisely in the `JAVA_OPTS` var

Comment: This would be a fine little script.

Comment: `java @file`, but it seems to require Java 9 or newer. Under Linux, you could use something like `java $(<file)` or whatever equivalent your shell provides.

Comment: My Tomcat is running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. This makes me inconvenient to set those options in `bin/setenv.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Before start tomcat executes `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` (or `%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat` for windows)

you can write `setenv.sh` file like

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS\
 -Ddev_key1=dev_value1\
 -Ddev_key2=dev_value2\
 -Ddev_key3=dev_value3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Absolutely.
As Mentioned by Alexander, you can add a setenv.sh file in the tomcat bin folder.
Here are some arguments which we are using.

```
# discourage address map swapping by setting Xms and Xmx to the same value
# http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Garbage+Collector+Performance+Issues
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms10000m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx10000m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:NewRatio=1"


# Increase maximum perm size for web base applications to 4x the default amount
# http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Memoryhttp://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Memory
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

# Reset the default stack size for threads to a lower value (by 1/10th original)
# By default this can be anywhere between 512k -> 1024k depending on x32 or x64
# bit Java version.
# http://www.springsource.com/files/uploads/tomcat/tomcatx-large-scale-deployments.pdf
# http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xss228k"

# Oracle Java as default, uses the serial garbage collector on the
# Full Tenured heap. The Young space is collected in parallel, but the
# Tenured is not. This means that at a time of load if a full collection
# event occurs, since the event is a 'stop-the-world' serial event then
# all application threads other than the garbage collector thread are
# taken off the CPU. This can have severe consequences if requests continue
# to accrue during these 'outage' periods. (specifically webservices, webapps)
# [Also enables adaptive sizing automatically]
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:+UseParallelGC"

# This is interpreted as a hint to the garbage collector that pause times
# of <nnn> milliseconds or less are desired. The garbage collector will
# adjust the  Java heap size and other garbage collection related parameters
# in an attempt to keep garbage collection pauses shorter than <nnn> milliseconds.
# http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/ergo5.html
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=300"

# A hint to the virtual machine that it.s desirable that not more than:
# 1 / (1 + GCTimeRation) of the application execution time be spent in
# the garbage collector.
# http://themindstorms.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/advanced-jvm-tuning-for-low-pause/
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:GCTimeRatio=9"

# The hotspot server JVM has specific code-path optimizations
# which yield an approximate 10% gain over the client version.
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server"

# Disable remote (distributed) garbage collection by Java clients
# and remove ability for applications to call explicit GC collection
#Changed the below line - Garbage 
#export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC  -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:logs/gc.log"
```